# Where did European armies find the huge amount of sulfur required for black powder?

Tags: military

Black powder requires charcoal, saltpeter and sulfur.

Charcoal and saltpeter can be made from natural renewable resources.

Sulfur has to be mined. Where can one find that much sulfur? All websites I have seen give evasive answer such as "near volcanoes".

Comment: Have you tried googling 'sulfur mines in Europe'?

Comment: By the time that Europe had large armies using black powder, they also had colonies around the world. Spain, for example, brought in sulfur from [New Spain](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41709176).

Comment: [Námafjall](https://is.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%A1mafjall), Iceland, was a major source. An early method to extract sulfur from ores is called [Sicilian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sicilian_method), which should also give a hint.

Comment: Amongst other sources of various purity, [iron pyrite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrite) "*also known as fool's gold, is an iron sulfide with the chemical formula FeS2 (iron (II) disulfide). Pyrite is the most abundant sulfide mineral.*" Iron pyrite can typically be found anyplace where precious metals are mined - and a whole lot more common which is part of the reason for it's being known as *fools' gold*.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens, I'm not seeing anything about the use of pyrites as a sulfur ore.  As a feedstock for producing various sulfur compounds, yes, but not for producing elemental sulfur.

Comment: @Mark: First line under [Sulfur - Production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur#Production): "*Sulfur may be found by itself and historically was usually obtained in this form; pyrite has also been a source of sulfur.*"

Comment: Coal can contain a lot of sulfur. However, saltpeter, not sulfur, was usually the limiting factor; the ratio was often 6-to-1. It came from urine, latrines, manure, and compost which had to be gathered. King Charles I had "urine laws" ordering "his loving subjects [to] carefully and constantly keep and preserve in some convenient vessels or receptacles fit for the purpose, all the urine of man during the whole year, and all the stale of beasts". https://web.archive.org/web/20060620135730/https://www-geology.ucdavis.edu/~cowen/~gel115/115CH16fertilizer.html